# Java 8 streams "ifPresent"

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn about streams and encountered a problem:
I want to get the minimal value of a list and assign it to an int variable.
For that I did the following:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    int smallest = list.stream().min(Integer::compareTo).get();
    System.out.println(smallest);
```

This works well and i get `1` as a result.
The issue is that the IDE gives the warning that `Optional.get` is called before checking for `.isPresent`.
To fix that i used the slightly different `ifPresent` method and tried the following:

```
int smallest = list.stream().min(Integer::compareTo).ifPresent(integer -> integer);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work since I get the warning: `Bad return type in Lambda, Integer cannot be converted to void.`
My question finally is: How can I assign the min value to the `int smallest` variable WITH checking ifPresent?

Comment: You first have to understand why you get an Optional, and not an integer: because the stream might be empty, and there might thus not be any minimum value. Then you need to decide what you want to get as a result if the stream is empty. Then, once you know what you want, you'll be able to pick the right way to get that result by looking at the documentation of Optional.

Comment: `ifPresent` takes a `Consumer` as its argument, which consumes the input value and returns nothing.

Comment: Hint: `list` initialization + adding can be simplified by `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3 );`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Stream#min` return `Optional` of result because in general stream can be empty so there can be no minimal value.

```
 Optional<Integer> minimal = list.stream().min(Integer::compareTo);
```

To get value from Optional you need to have some fallback value

```
Integer absent = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

The easiest would be to use `orElse`

```
Integer smallest = minimal.orElse(absent);
```

Little bit longer would be `isPresent`

```
Integer smallest = minimal.isPresent() ? minimal.get() : absent;
```

Comment: so the orElse method returns a Integer Type and not a Optional like the .min method?

Comment: yes, in this example it will be `Integer`. In general `Optional<T>` can contain value of any type `T`, so `orElse` returns that type `T`

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: A minor remark: Usually, the "not present"-value for the computation of the minimum is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and the "not present"-value for the computation of the maximum is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @Marco13 Why that?

Comment: @Eth The intention is to return a value that indicates a special case. (BTW: it also allows simple implementations like `int result=MAX_VALUE;for(i:a) result=min(result,i); return result;`). Of course, for `Integer`, one could argue about that: `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` could both be legitimate results. But when computing the minimum, returning the largest number gives a hint that no value was found at all. (This even makes more sense for `Double` and `POSITIVE_INFINITY`). It's done similarly in many libraries, and could be called a "best practice", or at least reasonably meets expectations.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
package lambdas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 7/31/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688119/java-8-streams-ifpresent
 */
public class MinimumExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int smallest = list.stream().min(Integer::compareTo).orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println(smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `.min` method returns a Optional, then the `.orElse` method needs to return an Integer. Does `.orElse` call the `.get` method then?

Comment: This code runs and works. It was seconded by the answer you accepted.   What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

The `ifPresent` method takes `Consumer<? super T>` as a parameter. Simply speaking, it should be an action without `return` statement. You could print the value if it's present, like

```
[...].ifPresent(System.out::print);
```

But it is not what about IDEA says. I think, you simply need to save an `Option<Integer>` instance and then check it by `isPresent`:

```
Optional<Integer> o = list.stream().min(Integer::compareTo);
if (o.isPresent()) {
    smallest = o.get();
}
```

Of course, there are more convenient ways with `orElse`:

```
smallest = o.orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

or with the ternary operator:

```
smallest = o.isPresent() ? o.get() : Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```